# Quorum deploy with Web3j timeout

Tags: web3j, quorum

SCENARIO:

I have the following code:

```
final String hostUrl = this.deployerProperties.getProperty("quorum.host.url");
final String hostPort = this.deployerProperties.getProperty("quorum.host.port");
final String host = hostUrl + ":" + hostPort;
final HttpService httpService = new HttpService(host);

this.admin = Admin.build(httpService);
this.quorum = Quorum.build(httpService);

final EthAccounts ethAccounts = this.quorum.ethAccounts().send();
final String ethFirstAccount = ethAccounts.getAccounts().get(0);
final PersonalUnlockAccount personalUnlockAccount = this.admin.personalUnlockAccount(ethFirstAccount, "").send();
if (!personalUnlockAccount.accountUnlocked()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Account " + ethFirstAccount + " can not be unlocked!");
} 

final List<String> privateFor = null;
int sleepDuration = 2 * 1000;
int attempts =50;
final ClientTransactionManager clientTransactionManager = new ClientTransactionManager(this.quorum, ethFirstAccount, ethFirstAccount, privateFor);

//final ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider = new DefaultGasProvider();
final ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider = new PersonalGasProvider();

final Tokens tokens = Tokens.deploy(this.quorum, clientTransactionManager, contractGasProvider).send();


public class PersonalGasProvider extends StaticGasProvider {
    public static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = DefaultGasProvider.GAS_LIMIT;
    public static final BigInteger GAS_PRICE = BigInteger.ZERO;

    public PersonalGasProvider() {
        super(GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
    }
}
```

When I execute the code. I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.TransactionException: Transaction receipt was not generated after 100 seconds for transaction: 0xbb0792515b9b84bb6d41956925027db0d8b4636470c475987b882993a257f974
>       at org.web3j.tx.response.PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.getTransactionReceipt(PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.java:51)
>       at org.web3j.tx.response.PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.waitForTransactionReceipt(PollingTransactionReceiptProcessor.java:29)
>       at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.processResponse(TransactionManager.java:72)
>       at org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager.executeTransaction(TransactionManager.java:51)
>       at org.web3j.tx.ManagedTransaction.send(ManagedTransaction.java:87)
>       at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeTransaction(Contract.java:291)
>       at org.web3j.tx.Contract.create(Contract.java:333)
>       at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:387)
>       at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$deployRemoteCall$10(Contract.java:496)
>       at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:30)

This java code works randomly because 10% of the executions the code finish the execution succesfully. But The other 90% of the executions appear the error.

The flow is the following:

1. Quorum 7nodes example deployed into a remote server
2. Smart-contract wrappers packaged into a JAR
3. A simple code execute the wrappers deploy method

Any idea about what happend?

**EDIT**

With this chages the error persist and the IDE warn me about that deploy constructor is deprecated

```
final ClientTransactionManager clientTransactionManager = new ClientTransactionManager(this.quorum, ethFirstAccount, /* ethFirstAccount */null, privateFor, attempts, sleepDuration);
final Users users = Users.deploy(this.quorum, clientTransactionManager, BigInteger.valueOf(0), BigInteger.valueOf(30000000) /* contractGasProvider */).send();
```

Comment: Hey, so web3j-quorum examples are far and few between, but we use it a lot in our acceptance tests. Here is an example link: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-acceptance-tests/blob/7233dcef7f4d682fe5fdd2d108130efc3df738c6/src/main/java/com/quorum/gauge/services/ContractService.java#L75

Comment: Thx for the help but I try the following edit of the post and the Exception persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen that issue before when the transaction was stuck on the pending queue (on an older version of quorum with a defect that could cause transactions to be stuck pending). I suggest you check that the transaction is hitting the geth node, and whether it's stuck on the pending queue.
If you have an old quorum version then try v2.2.3.

I don't have the Token contract code, but I tried your code with a SimpleContract and it works fine for me, except that I had to use my own GasProvider to get it to compile:

```
public class DeployGasProvider extends StaticGasProvider{

    public DeployGasProvider() {
        super(GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);
    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
ClientTransactionManager clientTransactionManager = new ClientTransactionManager(this.quorum, ethFirstAccount, ethFirstAccount, privateFor);

ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider = new DeployGasProvider();
SimpleStorage tokens = SimpleStorage.deploy(this.quorum, clientTransactionManager, contractGasProvider).send();
```

Comment: The trasanction appear pending in the geth console. Can you provide the values that you set to the GAS_PRICE and GAS_LIMIT values? Now I´m going to try increasing the version o fQuorum. Actually Im using the quorum 2.2.1 version. I will notice you  the advances. Many thxs !!

Comment: I'm using the values from the default:
GAS_LIMIT = 4300000L
GAS_PRICE = 22000000000L

Comment: Ok Im going to apply the values. But in a a Quorum environment it have sense to give a GAS_PRICE??

Comment: You're correct - it doesn't really make sense to supply a GAS_PRICE, but I believe it is replaced with zero under the covers (else my transactions would have been rejected by quorum).
Personally, I prefer to keep the GAS_PRICE, to keep the code more 'standard'.

Comment: Now the smart-contract deploy works fine. I increase the Quorum version to the 2.2.3. So many thanks !!